# Need clarification in the spring boot application

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot framework.
For understanding the flow I tried to implement the project given in the below article.

http://www.programming-free.com/2014/07/spring-data-rest-with-angularjs-crud.html?showComment=1470825194567#c2449594827994884785

Application works fine but I have few clarifications:-

1. I want to know how the insert/Update operation is working here as there is no API to support those.
2. Why we need to append '/tasks/search/..' before 'archivedfalse' for server communication?
   (is that any format we need to follow in the spring boot)

### app.js

```
$http.get(urlBase + '/tasks/search/findByTaskArchived?archivedfalse=0').
```

### TaskRepository.java

```
List<Task> findByTaskArchived(@Param("archivedfalse") int taskArchivedFalse);
```

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.

And someone can share links of simple crud application using springboot + angularjs + postgres that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert/update methods are available due to the repository extending from [`CrudRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html). It comes with a few operations (`save()`, `delete()`, `findAll()`, ...) by default, which allows you to call it without doing anything for it.

- For updating you use a `PUT` operation on the item resource ([documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_put))
- For deleting you use the `DELETE` operation on the item resource ([documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_delete))
- Creating a new item can be done by using the `POST` operation on the collection resource ([documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_post))

How the paths behave is [documented](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.configuring-the-rest-url-path). For the `/tasks` part, it will use your domain class:

> By default, the exporter will expose your CrudRepository using the name of the domain class. Spring Data REST also applies the Evo Inflector to pluralize this word.

A bit lower in the documentation you can find that it uses the method name of your query methods for your path:

> If you have query methods defined, those also default to be exposed by their name

And it also mentions that they're all prepended by the `/search` path segment:

> ℹ️ All query method resources are exposed under the resource `search`.